# grep -v does not return complement of grep

Tags: grep, regular-expression, filter

I want to filter a file for lines starting with a space. I use the following command:

```
grep -v "^ " < input > input_no_starting_space
```

To double check my results, I run the following:

```
grep "^ " < input > double_check
```

and then count the number of lines in `input_no_starting_space` and `double_check` to see whether their sum adds up to the number of lines in `input`. For this I use `wc -l`.

For some reason, this check fails. Meaning, the sum of the number of lines is less than the number of lines in `input`. My file has millions of lines, but I cannot seem to reproduce the issue on a small example. Is there by any chance something wrong with the way I use grep (since I would expect that `grep` and `grep -v` always give the complement of one another), or is this more likely an artifact in my file? In case of the latter, what could this artifact be?

This is using GNU grep 3.4 on Ubuntu 20.04.3.

Comment: `diff -u <(cat input_no_starting_space double_check | sort) <(sort < input)`

Comment: This is going to be hard to debug without an example (and you can't easily give an example, I know). I assume you're counting the lines with `wc -l`, right? Does using `/usr/bin/grep -v "^ " ` and `/usr/bin/grep "^ "` make any difference? I'm thinking you might have an alias that's adding `--color=always` or something and that could be confusing things. I would also try passing the file through `dos2unix` or `sed -i 's/\r//g'`, just in case, although I don't really see how the `\r` would cause this specific behavior.

Comment: Are you sure nothing appends to `input` in the meantime?

Comment: @terdon Yes, I use `wc -l` indeed. I tried using `/bin/grep` as well as doing the `sed` command before, but still the same behavior

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Nothing gets appended indeed, I only perform the `grep` commands. I also check the number of lines both before and after executing the `grep`

Comment: run the command I commented before to see what the difference is.

Comment: Consider showing the commands that you used to do the counting and comparison of the number of lines. There might be something wrong there that is easy to spot.

Comment: How many lines of difference do you have between your files? Do you try to use `grep --count` option to count lines ? Do you have the same result than `wc -l` ?

Comment: Remember, `wc-l` does not count the "last" line if it is not terminated by "\n" (LF)

Comment: @ArnaudValmary my `input` file has 385,752,916 lines, `input_no_starting_space` has 36,669,628 lines, and `double_check` has 17 lines. I use `wc -l`. I am currently running the `diff` command of @user253751

Comment: @user253751 the diff just outputs: `Binary files /dev/fd/63 and/dev/fd/62 differ`. Does that mean it does not consider my files as just text? (It should, btw)

Comment: @Stijn Yes. Try `grep` commands with `-a` option

Comment: That was it! Using `grep -a` the line numbers add up. I still find it weird, regardless of interpreting something as text or binary, that `grep` and `grep -v` don't produce a complement of each other. But thanks for the help! Feel free to make an official answer to this post. (I can also do it myself)

Comment: @Stijn That is interesting because yes, it means there's something in your file that's making it not be considered as text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be, your `input_file` do not contains only text data.

Try to use `grep` with `-a` option.

See also `--binary-files=TYPE` option for `grep` command and `man grep` first paragraph about data enconding and NULL value:

> If a file's data or metadata indicate that the file contains binary data, assume that the file is of type TYPE. Non-text bytes indicate binary data; these are either output bytes that are improperly encoded for the current locale, or null input bytes when the -z option is not given.